# Крашиться приложение -java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

запуск через код

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    private final List<Person> mItems;


    public RVAdapter(ArrayList<Person> mItems) {
        this.mItems =   mItems;

    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public final TextView mTextView;
        private final TextView textContent;

        ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            textContent= itemView.findViewById(R.id.textContent);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("RecyclerView")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, final int position) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        itemViewHolder.mTextView.setText(mItems.get(position).name);
        //noinspection deprecation
        itemViewHolder.textContent.setText(mItems.get( position).textContent );
        itemViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
                Context context= v.getContext();
                Intent i = new Intent(context,JsonActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("text",(mItems.get(position).textContent)); // put image data in Intent
                context.startActivity(i); // start Intent

            }


        });}

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }
```

код обработки

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonActivity extends Activity {
    //String s=null;

    ProgressDialog PD;

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); // get Intent which we set from Previous Activity
        String s = extras != null ? extras.getString( "text" ) : null;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        PD = new ProgressDialog(this);
        PD.setMessage("Loading.....");
        PD.setCancelable(false);

        //  makejsonobjreq();

        //}

        //private void makejsonobjreq() {
        PD.show();
        String url = ("http://proforientator.info/?json=get_page&"+s);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                JSONObject page = response.optJSONObject("page" );

                // String name = page.optString("title");

                String region = page.optString("content");

                          tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(region).toString());


                PD.dismiss();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                PD.dismiss();
            }
        });
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jsonObjReq, "jreq");
    }
}
```

строка ошибки

```
 MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(jsonObjReq, "jreq");
```

класс куда обращается

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Application;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

@SuppressLint("Registered")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getReqQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> JsonObjectRequest addToReqQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {

        getReqQueue().add(req);
        return null;
    }

    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req) {

        getReqQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingReq(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Прописан ли класс `Application` в манифесте?

Comment: сейчас посмотрю))

Comment: Ура заработало!

Comment: Я написал в ответ - вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела поста)

Answer (score 2):

У вас не вызываете `onCreate` метод, где вы инициализируете `private static MyApplication mInstance` ибо ваш класс не указан в качестве класса приложения в манифесте. Надо прописать так:

(Если класс App лежит в пакете ru.stackoverflow.android)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ru.stackoverflow.android">

    <application
        android:name="ru.stackoverflow.android.MyApplication"
```